# Find all user with specific role in flow builder

Tags: visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow

I have lookup field to role object in user object. how can I get all user with roles
[image]

Comment: Did you try adding UserRoleId in the filter criteria's value?

Comment: yes I tried since it is lookup field and I hv to filter by string

Answer (score 1):

To filter by the Role, you need to first retrieve the Role ID via a Get Records element. From there you can use that in your Get Records element to get the Users.